# Biblatex - count cites from different bibliographies separately

Tags: biblatex, bibliographies, automation

I have three separate bibliography files as follows:

```
\newtotcounter{no_journals}
\newtotcounter{no_conferences}
\newtotcounter{no_thesis}

\AtEveryBibitem{\stepcounter{no_journals}}

\defbibheading{journals}{International Journals}
\defbibheading{conferences}{International Conferences}
\defbibheading{thesis}{Thesis Conducted}

\addbibresource[label=journals]{journals}
\addbibresource[label=conferences]{conferences}
\addbibresource[label=thesis]{pfc}
```

And I would like to count the number of total cites that I have per each of them. Each entry within the same .bib file has the same key; this is, every entry of the "journals.bib" file has:

```
keywords={journals}
```

In my bibliography, I have separate subsections for each of them:

```
\subsection*{International Journals}\label{sec:journals}

    \AtNextBibliography

    \begin{refsection}[journals.bib]
    \nocite{*}
    \begin{refcontext}
    \printbibliography
    \end{refcontext}
    \end{refsection}

    \begin{itemize}
        \item Number of International Journals: \total{no_journals}\
    \end{itemize}
```

How can I can count the number of journals, conferences and thesis separately using \ateverybibitem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you use `keywords` in your `.bib` file you can use them to check which counter to step

```
\AtEveryBibitem{%
  \ifkeyword{journals}{\stepcounter{no_journals}}{}%
  \ifkeyword{conferences}{\stepcounter{no_conferences}}{}%
  \ifkeyword{thesis}{\stepcounter{no_thesis}}{}%
}
```

But you could also filter by entry type. If all journal contributions are `@article`, all conferences `@inproceedings` etc., you could go for

```
\AtEveryBibitem{%
  \ifentrytype{article}{\stepcounter{no_journals}}{}%
  \ifentrytype{inproceedings}{\stepcounter{no_conferences}}{}%
  \ifentrytype{thesis}{\stepcounter{no_thesis}}{}%
}
```

---

Neither of the two approaches requires you to have the different types of contributions in separate `.bib` files. AFAICS with the code you posted, the `label=...` argument to `\addbibresource` is also not used. The `\begin{refcontext}...\end{refcontext}` is not used either (it could be used to change the sorting, but does not sort any purpose in the code snippet you posted.) With appropriate filtering by keyword or type in `\printbibliography` you won't even need the `\begin{refsection}...\end{refsection}`.