# Getting the number of references from \printbibliography

Tags: biblatex

Is there a way to define a label within \printbibliography in order to automatically get the number of references.

I would typically like to do:

```
\section{Articles (\ref{no_articles})}

\printbibliography[heading=none, keyword=my_article]\label{no_articles}
```

But unfortunately, `\ref{no_articles}` points to the section number and not to the total number of references.

Many thanks!

Comment: The label will never return the number of references. If you really need to know how many refs you have, just choose a numbered style, run your file again, find out how many there are, and undo the style -- of course if you're already using a numeric style you always know how many there are.

Comment: I think https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/163451/total-number-of-citations can be used here as well.

Comment: See for example https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/404238/35864 and https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/454182/35864.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Many thanks to @Marijn and @moewe, indeed the following did the trick:

In the preamble:

```
\usepackage{totcount}
\newtotcounter{no_refs}
\AtEveryBibitem{\ifkeyword{my_keyword}{\stepcounter{no_refs}}{}}
```

And later in the document:

```
\subsection{References (\the\totvalue{no_refs})}
\printbibliography[heading=none, keyword=my_keyword]
```

NB: I have read that `\AtNextBibliography`can be used to reset all counters after a previous `printbibliography` statetment, but this did not work here, the counter kept accumulating.